# std::map inizialitazion (only one time)

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, garbage

I have a function that translates data using std::map

```
struct HistoParameter
{
  int nbins;
  float first;
  float last;
  HistoParameter(int _nbins, int _first, int _last) :
    nbins(_nbins), first(_first), last(_last) {};
};

HistoParameter* variable_to_parameter(char* var_name)
{
  std::map<const std::string, HistoParameter*> hp;
  hp[std::string("ph_pt")] = new HistoParameter(100,0,22000);
  hp[std::string("ph_eta")] = new HistoParameter(100,-3,3);
  // ...
  return hp[var_name];
}
```

My struct is very light, but image it can be heavy. The prolem is that every time I call this function it create a lot of HistoParameter objects, maybe a switch case is more efficient. First question: I'm creating garbage?

Second solution:

```
bool first_time = true;
HistoParameter* variable_to_parameter(char* var_name)
{
  static std::map<const std::string, HistoParameter*> hp;
  if (first_time)
    {
  hp[std::string("ph_pt")] = new HistoParameter(100,0,22000);
  hp[std::string("ph_eta")] = new HistoParameter(100,-3,3);
  // ...
    }
  first_time = false;
  return hp[var_name];
```

is it ok? Better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution should certainly improve efficiency, but isn't (at least IMO) the best implementation possible. First of all, it makes `first_time` publicly visible, even though only `variable_to_parameter` actually cares about it. You've already made `hp` a static variable in the function, and `first_time` should be as well.

Second, I would not use pointers and/or dynamic allocation for the HistoParameter values. At one int and two floats, there's simply no reason to do so. If you're really passing them around so much that copying became a problem, you'd probably be better off using some sort of smart pointer class instead of a raw pointer -- the latter is more difficult to use and much more difficult to make exception safe.

Third, I'd consider whether it's worthwhile to make variable_to_parameter into a functor instead of a function. In this case, you'd initialize the map in the ctor, so you wouldn't have to check whether it was initialized every time `operator()` was invoked. You can also combine the two, by have a static map in the functor. The ctor initializes it if it doesn't exist, and operator() just does a lookup.

Finally, I'd note that `map::operator[]` is primarily useful for inserting items -- it creates an item with the specified key if it doesn't exist, but when you're looking for an item, you usually don't want to create an item. For this, you're generally better off using `map.find()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The second solution seems OK to me - you can say:

```
if ( hp.empty() ) {
   // populate map
}
```

I would also consider making it a map of values rather than pointers - I don't see you need dynamic allocation here:

```
 std::map <std::string, HistoParameter> hp;
```

then:

```
 hp["ph_pt"] = HistoParameter(100,0,22000);
```

Note you don't need the explicit std::string conversion. Or better still:

```
 hp.insert( std::make_pair( "ph_pt", HistoParameter(100,0,22000 )));
```

Comment: Heh, the same ideas, but you beat me on make_pair. Forgot that it's not only make_tuple out there -_-.

Comment: I like ht.empty() because I can to not use a global variable. I'm using pointer because in future this class can become very different and heavier.

Comment: Well you could make that change when and if it becomes necessary - that's one of the main reasons for using encapsulation. As it stands, if you don't use smart pointers you have some resource leak issues. As the map is static, these may not matter, but still...

Comment: @wiso, you can still pass/return pointers to the class in the map. Pointers *can* be used on non-dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: @Kornel Kisielewicz, you can use make_tuple here as well, if you are referring to boost::make_tuple, which is just a drop-in replacement.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, in the OP's code, even the map is static, memory leaks still happens, because it creates new objects at each call, while there's only one key available,  unless he's using std::multimap.

Answer (score 3):

The first solution produces a lot of garbage. Why don't you return the class by value? It's quite lightweight, and you wouln't have to dynamically allocate it.

```
HistoParameter variable_to_parameter(char* var_name)
{
  static std::map<const std::string, HistoParameter> hp;
  if ( hp.empty() )
  {
    hp.insert( std::make_pair( "ph_pt", HistoParameter(100,0,22000) ) );
    hp.insert( std::make_pair( "ph_eta", HistoParameter(100,-3,3) ) );
  //...
  }
  return hp[var_name];
}
```

If the class returned gets larger, and you want a power-tool, then try out [boost::flyweight](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/flyweight/doc/tutorial/index.html).

If you don't want to pass back a big structure, you can do:

```
HistoParameter& variable_to_parameter(char* var_name)
{
  // same code
}
```

... and even throw in a `const` if you want it immutable.

**Edit:** added make_pair, as suggested by Niel.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a std::map< std::string, HistoParameter *> member and do

```
InitializeHistoParameter() 
{
   myMap["ph_pt"] = new ...
   myMap["ph_eta"] = new ...
}
```

And then

```
HistoParameter* variable_to_parameter(char* var_name) 
{
    return myMap[var_name];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

either way, you are creating memory leak.
each time the `=` operator is called, for example:

```
hp[std::string("ph_pt")] = new HistoParameter(100,0,22000);
```

you are creating a new HistoParameter object and pairing the key "ph" with this most recent object, leaving the previous one dangling.
If creating a new object each time is your actual intent, you probably need to call

```
delete hp[std::string("ph_pt")];
```

before the `new` operation.

My suggestion is to avoid raw `new` operations as much as possible and resort to smart pointers such as [boost::share_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) for object life time management.